# scrollLeft to anchor on horizontal website gets messy after scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, horizontal-scrolling, nowrap

I'm currently working on a new web project which is a horizontal scrolling portfolio site. I'm almost done, there is just one piece of code that won't work like its supposed to.

I've got a burger menu in the top left of the screen that contains anchor links that are supposed to smoothly scroll to the referenced id. Problem is that as soon as you scroll the page, the scroll distance gets messed up and the scroll distance gets totally messed up.

Here is the link to the page: http://www.timbrack.de/#portfolio

To reproduce the error hit the burger menu and click on 'about' it will just scroll backwards for a couple of pixels even though about is on the right of the portfolio section...

I use white-space: nowrap for the containers to fit horizontally like this:

```
body {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.content_container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 500px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

the piece of script for scrolling looks like this:

```
$(".scroll").bind("click",function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);

        $("body").stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr("href")).offset().left
        }, 1200);
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

Do you guys have any idea why the scrolling distance gets so messed up?

Cheers
Tim

Comment: by opening up my console and typing: `$("body").scrollLeft()` while I'm at your portfolio section I can see that JS doesn't think there's anything to scroll.

I would suggest creating a `<div>` inside the body with a fixed width and placing all your content in that container... then your body will be able to scroll. Maybe even `nowrap` will work instead of fixed-width, but im dubious.

Comment: I can't find the hamburger menu, so I can't see what the issue might be. I would however suggest you to never override default scrolling behaviour. Currently I'm not able to use two finger scrolling on my trackpad.

Comment: Also, if you want your site to be scrollable in horizontal please not that this is an UX antipattern - un mobile this is left-right swipe is often "go back / go forth" and so it is on my MacBook - if I scroll left to the edge i am triggering "go back" in both Chrome and Safari and I don't like that :)